# How to display a single terminal in two columns?

Tags: linux, terminal

When viewing a PDF on a wide screen monitor, the viewer can display two pages one next to the other. Is it possible to do something like this for a terminal window so that I can meaningfully utilize use the area of a wide screen?

The idea is simple. Let's say I issue `vdir`. Then I'd like to have the last part of the listing in the right column and the last but one part in the left column. I tried to mimic this in vim to show how it might look like:

[image: Screenshot]

Note: I'm not looking for splitting the window into two separate terminals like `tmux` offers. I want to have one terminal, just that its "bottom" part is mapped to the right column and its "top" part into the left one.

Comment: Nice idea. I don't know of any that does that currently. But in most a simple key combo (Shift-pgup) will quickly show the scrollback buffer.

Comment: You could get the two sides showing the same terminal by splitting a terminal multiplexer, like tmux, nesting two instances and attaching them both to the same socket. Keeping one of the two scrolled up is the challenging part.

Comment: @Keith Yes, I use that, but it doesn't help me utilize the whole screen.

Comment: I'm interested in this now, so +1 and starred.

Answer (score 8):

This question appears to be very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963720/multi-column-terminal-multiplexer. See answers over there.

The only implementation I am aware of is my own [two column virtual terminal](http://subdivi.de/~helmut/tcvt/). Feedback (via email) is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

This feature appears to be present in Konsole, the KDE terminal (also installeable for other desktop environments):

> The split-view mode, pictured below, is inspired by GNU
>   Screen. It is a console output cloning tool so that you can see two
>   views of the same scroll buffer. For example, if you are a developer,
>   and you need to compile something really big (like say, KDE), then you
>   can read through the scroll at your own pace on one side, while still
>   monitor the output progress simultaneously.

http://dot.kde.org/2007/05/23/road-kde-4-konsole-gets-overhaul

[image: Konsole, featuring window split]

Comment: Looks promising. What I'd like to achieve that both views scroll, displaying together last _2n_ lines.